# Concurrent requests to Nginx Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I am having a problem with my server dealing with a large volume of concurrent users signing on and operating at the same time. Our business case requires the user base to be logging in at the exact same time (1 min window) and performing various operations in our application. Once the server goes past a 1000 concurrent users, the website starts loading very slowly and constant giving 502 errors.

We have reviewed the server metrics (CPU, RAM, Data traffic utilization) on the cloud are most resources are operating at below 10%. Scaling up the server doesn't help.

While the website is constant giving 502 errors are responding after a long time, any direct database queries and SSH connection are working fine. As such we have concluded that issue is primarily focused on the number of concurrent requests the server is handling due to any Nginx or Gunicorn configuration we may have set up incorrectly.

Please advice on any possible incorrect configuration (or any other solution) to this issue :

Server info :

Server specs - AWS c4.8xlarge ( CPU and RAM)
Web Server -Nginx
Backend Server -Gunicorn

[nginx conf image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIM19.png)[Gunicorn conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zRCN.png)

Comment: Why not multiple small instances with nginx/gunicorn behind a load balancer or it doesn't suit your config?

Comment: we tried  that also , but we are not able to achieve the expected  request limit .

Comment: by the way, it's more like an application issue rather than aws services. You need to check logs for ngnix and other applications. set debug logging in ngnix and see what's happening.